# How to use .Values in other variable loops

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Below is my case:

```
{{- $v := (.Files.Get "values-productpage.yaml") | fromYaml }}.   
   spec:
     {{- range $key, $value := $v.containers }}
     containers:
     - name: {{ $value.name }}
       image: {{.Values.productpage_image}}:latest
```

Here when reaching `.Values.productpage_image`, it reports: `can't evaluate field productpage_image in type interface {}`.

Is there any usage error here?  Why can I not use `.Values.xxx` in this loop?  If I move the `.Values` to the first line, there is no error.

Answer (score 12):

You can simply use `$` to get to the root scope

Without defining what `$root` is, you can references `.Values` as `$.Values` from within a loop, or any other scope.

Source: https://github.com/kubeapps/kubeapps/pull/1057

Comment: It works within loops, but unfortunately, $.Values does not provide access to the root scope when a sub-context has been passed to a template: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3167 - this is a fundamental shortcoming of Helm+Go templates.

Answer (score 3):

As @abinet explained properly about the reason, I'll share my solution for that( which helped me a lot, and I hope that will save you time):

First, I saved the scope:
    `{{- $root := . -}}`

and after that , I called the .Value inside the loop context like this:
`{{ $root.Values.data }}`

so basically , you code should be look like:

```
{{- $root := . -}}

{{- $v := (.Files.Get "values-productpage.yaml") | fromYaml }}.   
  spec:
   {{- range $key, $value := $v.containers }}
   containers:
   - name: {{ $value.name }}
     image: {{$root.Values.productpage_image}}:latest
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because range changes a scope (see detailed description here https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures.md#looping-with-the-range-action).

You can assign `.Values.productpage_image` to the variable outside the range and use inside.